# I'd like to always save label(text) in yolov5 by without typing --save-txt

Tags: python, yolov5

I'd like to always save label(text) in yolov5 by without typing --save-txt. How can I change on detect.py.

Please supporting. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to `detect.py` and there in the parser argument section which is down below add an extra line in the `--save-txt` line that is `default='True'`.